# how to hide remove link when there is only one row/item in the form using link_to_remove_association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am using cocoon gem to add/remove a record 'on the fly' from a form in rails. Is there a way to hide the remove link which is added on the page using link_to_remove_association if there is only one row/item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. As the rows were being added from JS, controlling the hiding/showing of the remove link had to be handled from JS itself and not rails.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container')
      .on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
        if($(".fields-row").length > 1){
          $(".remove_fields")[0].style.display="block";
        }else{
          $(".remove_fields")[0].style.display="none";
        }
      })
      .on("cocoon:after-remove", function() {
        if($(".fields-row").length == 1){
          $(".remove_fields")[0].style.display="none";
        }else{
          $(".remove_fields")[0].style.display="block";
        }
      });
});
```

.remove_fields class is added to the `<a>` tag automatically when using link_to_remove_association

For some reason .show()/.hide() methods of JQuery were not working, that is why I have used .style.display

Answer (score 1):

I would just wrap it in an if block, eg

```
<% if foos.size > 0 %>
  <% link_to "Remove", remove_foo_path(foo) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use FormBuilder index.

HAML:

```
.nested_fields
  %h3 Nested object
  - unless f.index == 0
    = link_to_remove_association "remove", f
```